# Why dont we use 'this' in getters?

Tags: java, oop, object

For instance, lets say that we have an object called `car` which is a part of `Cars` class and it has a `color` property. And assuming that we have a getter for the color such that:

```
public String getColor(){
  return color;
}
```

But should not it be `this.color`? If not, why?

Comment: Because it makes no difference there.

Comment: It **can be**, but it doesn't need to be. The result would be exactly the same.

Comment: When would it be a bad idea to not include "this"?

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. I find unnecessary use of `this` clutter, annoying and hard to read, but I know people who have the exact opposite opinion.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. And as I am hunting the daily limit today ... I am very very grateful ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `this` implicitly here. When you "leave" out the object on which you "access" a field or call a method ... then that is the same as saying `this.field` or `this.foo()` Unless of course, that the name you are using refers to a local variable for example. So, just to be precise: when you have code such as

```
void setter(Whatever foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
```

then of course you **have** to use `this` in order to differentiate between the *field* foo and the local variable foo that is *shadowing* that field.

Any slightly experienced Java programmer knows that. Therefore it is good practice to not write down `this` here. Keep in mind: you write your code so that your *human* readers understand what is going on. The compiler and IDEs are fine with using this ... or not using this. But for your human readers it simply means a little bit *less* of information to process when you leave out this keyword here.

That is all there is to *this*.

Comment: You forgot to state that this is implicite because there is no other variable in that scope with the same name. The perfect example is a setter.

Comment: @AxelH Very valid point. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

'this' always represents current object. SO if you say this.color it's excatly same as simply say 'color'. You can doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: Since you mention the `current object`, it is interesting to note that this is the object defining the method, for nested class, this become a bit more complicated ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's superfluous. In general you use the `this.something` only if you have a parameter in the method's signature with the same name. Classical example are constructors:

```
public MyClass(String val1, String val2) {
    this.val1 = val1;
    this.val2 = val2;
}
```

It was used more often in the past when there was no syntax highlighting in IDEs that included the different presentation of member and local variables. Then `this` was used to make it easier to distinguish between these two types of variables.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks!

Comment: "_Then this was used to make it easier to distinguish between these two types of variables._" If you remove `this.` in your example, the result won't be the same at all. That's not just to be readable for you, but also for the compiler to know what variable to use.

Comment: @AxelH In my second paragraph I was explaining why `this` was used more often in situations where it wasn't needed. It has nothing to do with the previous example of code where `this` is required.

Comment: But your reasons are _before syntax highlighting_ and _easier to distinguish_. There is a real need for `this`, that you said in the first part. So that second part kind of say the opposite, so this is a good and bad answer ^^